# What mistake did I make resulting in the error: "Property "item" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance."?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

I'm getting the error:

> "Property "item" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance."

---

I don't know exactly why, but I was thinking maybe it's because there's an async fetch involved and the template renders before the fetch can be completed?

If that's the case, how do you fix that in Vue3 with "script setup"? I know how to handle that in React, but what is the Vue equivalent to

```
{item && <Component />}
```

? I already tried a "v-if" like this:

```
<div class="homescreen_products" v-if="items" :v-for="item in items">
```

but that doesn't fix anything. Did I do this wrong? Do I use a lifecycle hook like "beforeMount" or "mounted"? I was under the impression that this wasn't necessary with "script setup"?

---

If it's not the async fetch thing, did I pass the props wrong? Did I try to render the props wrong? Does it have something to do with using VueX? What causes the "...accessed during render but is not defined on instance" error?

Here's the full code:

**store.js**

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    productsArray: [],
    checkoutCart: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_ITEM_TO_CART(state, payload) {
      state.checkoutCart.push(payload);
    },
    INIT_PRODUCTS(state, payload) {
      state.productsArray = payload;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    cartAdd({ commit }, payload) {
      console.log("cartAdd()/payload= ", payload);
      commit("ADD_ITEM_TO_CART", payload);
    },

    getAllProducts({ commit }) {
      fetch("http://localhost:5000")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("data= ", data);
          commit("INIT_PRODUCTS", data);
        });
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getCheckout: (state) => state.checkoutCart,
    getProducts: (state) => state.productsArray,
  }
});
```

**ParentComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="homescreen">
    <h2 class="homescreen_title">Latest Products</h2>
    <div class="homescreen_products" :v-for="item in items">
      <ChildComponent :description="item.description" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import ChildComponent from "../ChildComponent/ChildComponent.vue";
    import { useStore } from "vuex";
    import { computed } from "vue";

    const store = useStore();

    const getProducts = async () => {
      await store.dispatch("getAllProducts");
    };

    getProducts();

    const items = computed(() => store.getters.getProducts);

</script>
```

**ChildComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="product">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="" />
    <div class="product_info">
        {{ description }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    defineProps({
      description: String,
    });

</script>
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

"Items" is being populated correctly. When I use this code instead of the "v-for" I have in the OP:

```
<div class="homescreen_products">
    {{items}}
</div>
```

it gets rendered in the template like this:

[i.imgur.com/IUjEjN5.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrkG6.png)

---

**EDIT 3:** @monstis

When I change my ParentComponent to:

```
<template lang="">
  <div class="homescreen">
    <h2 class="homescreen_title">Latest Products</h2>
    <div v-if="items">
      <div class="homescreen_products" v-for="item in items">
        <ProductScreen :description="item.description" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

With the

-"v-if" moved to a parent div

-"v-for" without the binding (":v-for")

it still doesn't work. I'm getting the error:

> error  Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/require-v-for-key

Comment: This type of error generally occurs when you try to render any property (item in your case) in your template but did not define it anywhere. So, before accessing the `item`, check if it is defined in the data or computed or methods, etc.

Comment: You can run a console.log on this **"items"** array to verify that the array is being loaded correctly and your for is reading a populated array!

Comment: You used the directive v-for like a binding, you used the colon (**:v-for**. Try to remove it and keep just **v-for**

Comment: the :v-for binding is required, when I take away the colon I get the error: `"Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives.eslintvue/require-v-for-key"`

Comment: Items is loading correctly. When I use this code: `<div class="homescreen_products">{{items}}</div>`, instead of the "v-for" I have in the OP.......it gets rendered to the template like this:  https://i.imgur.com/IUjEjN5.png

Comment: `v-for` must be used without colon. The warning for using `v-for` without `:key` is normal. Vue needs a unique identifier for each item so that when you update the items it can optimise rendering and reuse DOM elements existing both old and new collection. Without specifying a `:key`, the `index` is used, under the hood, which potentially messes up animations or item updates. Most importantly, the `:key` expectation message is a ***warning***, whereas using `:v-for` yields an ***error***. I strongly suggest reading [the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for).

Comment: @RohitJidal, suggesting answering the question as a comment does not align with SO recommendations, even when the mistake is only one character. If you can find a similar question with an accepted answer, mark it as duplicate, but don't suggest replacing a correct answer with a comment. Please read [answer].

Comment: OP doesn't understand the difference between `:v-for` and `v-for` and they came here for an answer. Answers are permanent and based on facts. Comments are for opinions, clarifications and suggestions. Comments are much more volatile than answers and, most importantly, are not indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use vbind with v-for but you should use the :key with v-for. And you should use the onMounted with script setup.